# Working with Parameters containing Escaped Characters in Python Config file

Tags: python, escaping, configparser

I have a config file that I'm reading using the following code:

```
import configparser as cp
config = cp.ConfigParser()
config.read('MTXXX.ini')
MT=identify_MT(msgtext)
schema_file = config.get(MT,'kbfile')
fold_text = config.get(MT,'fold')
```

The relevant section of the config file looks like this:

```
[536]
kbfile=MT536.kb
fold=:16S:TRANSDET\n
```

Later I try to find text contained in a dictionary that matches the 'fold' parameter, I've found that if I find that text using the following function:

```
    def test (find_text)
        return {k for k, v in dictionary.items() if find_text in v}
```

I get different results if I call that function in one of two ways:

```
test(fold_text)
```

Fails to find the data I want, but:

```
test(':16S:TRANSDET\n')
```

returns the results I *know* are there.

And, if I print the content of the dictionary, I can see that it is, as expected, shown as

```
:16S:TRANSDET\n
```

So, it matches when I enter the search text directly, but doesn't find a match when I load the same text in from a config file.

I'm guessing that there's some magic being applied here when reading/handling the \n character pattern in from the config file, but don't know how to get it to work the way I want it to.

I want to be able to parameterise using escape characters but it seems I'm blocked from doing this due to some internal mechanism.

Is there some switch I can apply to the config reader, or some extra parsing I can do to get the behavior I want? Or perhaps there's an alternate solution. I do find the configparser module convenient to use, but perhaps this is a limitation that requires an alternative, or even self-built module to lift data out of a parameter file.

Comment: I've come across a similar situation after writing a config file in JSON format - it's the same root cause, I'm benefiting from the utility of a well defined format (JSON/Config File) but that comes at the cost of enforcing particular escaping conventions. I suspect I'm asking to have my cake and eat it in this case.